# How can I swap values in string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, arraylist

I want to swap `data[0]` to `data[2]`..

example input: `hitman, 222, black, white`

output: `222, hitman, black, white`

```java
public void display() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Database.txt"));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String data[] = new String[4];
            data = s.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int temp = 0;
                data[i] = data[i].replaceAll(", $", "");
                /// iwant to swap data[0] and data[1] in here
                System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far?  Even if it doesn't work, it helps us know where to start assisting you (and I suspect the lack of demonstrated effort is why this question has been marked down).

Comment: i already modify it

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, just store the value you want to replace in a string and reassign it.

```java
String[] data = {"hitman", "222", "black", "white"};
String tmp = data[0];
data[0] = data[1];
data[1] = tmp;

for (String i : data) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

output:

```
222
hitman
black
white
```

Comment: 222, 222, black , white

Comment: that is because you need to store the 0th index value of the array in a string and reassign it to the 1st index. as answered above.

Comment: and now the output went